# Read and write files from a protected shared folder on another device

Tags: java, directory, password-protection

How to read and write files from a protected shared folder on another device using Java?

I'm currently working on a backup program which backups all the computers we use at home to a NAS system. This NAS has a shared folder which is used to store the backup files in. This shared folder is protected with a username and password.

I would like to read and write files to this system using Java. Reading and writing files is easy, the problem is though, it isn't possible to read and write files from this shared folder because user credentials are required. How to I login automatically on this shared folder with supplied user credentials using Java, before using this shared folder?

So, the problem doesn't have anything to do with the file path I should be using, or the way I should reach this folder. The problem I have is, that the Java program needs to login automatically on this shared folder with supplied user credentials before reading or writing any files from this external file system.

Comment: Do you know what protocol your shared folder is using to send and authenticate the data in the shared folder? Is it a web console via HTTP Basic Auth? Is it an SSH2 key. How do you access this shared folder from another computer, etc?

Comment: No I don't really know what protocol is used. I'm sure though FTP is not used. This NAS is running on our local network. I created a folder which is a shared folder on the system. I can tell you that I'm able to access the shared folder from any computer using the windows explorer, since this folder is shown in network locations. That's the only thing I know about it sadly. Oh and also, I'm able to access the shared folder using the following path: ` \\JARVIS\ ` but I don't think this helps a lot. So yeah, I'm able to access it as network directory. I don't know what protocol is used.

Comment: Btw, it's a Synology NAS, which is running DSM (Which is their own operating system for their NAS devices). I'll take a look on their pages to find out what protocol is used.

Comment: I think it's using SMB, but I'm not sure because the Synology pages won't tell me, sadly. I just searched for `Shared Folders Protocol` and I landed on [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734393%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), which looks realistic. SMB is a server system though, not a protocol. This might help a bit.